# How to set Service Load Balancer request timeouts on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Service on GKE of type LoadBalancer that points to a GKE deployment running nginx. My nginx has all of the timeouts set to 10 minutes, yet HTTP/HTTPS requests that have to wait on processing before receiving a response get cutoff with 500 errors after 30 seconds. My settings:

```
http {
    proxy_read_timeout 600s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    keepalive_timeout 600s;
    send_timeout 600s;
}
```

Apparently there are default settings of 30 seconds in the LoadBalancer somewhere.

After pouring through documentation, I've only found a step-through at Google that outlines setting an Ingress with back-end service Load Balancer with a timeout but can't find how to do that on a Service that's Type=LoadBalancer for use with GKE. I've also reviewed all of the Kubernetes documentation for versions 1.7+ (we're on 1.8.7-gke.1) and nothing about setting a timeout. Is there a setting I can add to my yaml file to do this?

If it helps I found the following for AWS, which appears to be what I would need to have on GKE:

```
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-connection-idle-timeout: "60"
```

Comment: Hi, check the update of the answer

Answer (score 5):

As of April 2021 you can do this via GKE/GCE configuration.  [Here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-features#create_backendconfig) are the instructions.
Essentially you create a `BackendConfig` resource similar to this:

```yaml
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-backendconfig
spec:
  timeoutSec: 40
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 60
```

(`kubectl apply -f my-backendconfig.yaml`)

and then connect it to your GKE service resource with an annotation:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"my-backendconfig"}}'
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    purpose: bsc-config-demo
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
```

(`kubectl apply -f my-service.yaml`)

If you prefer, the BackendConfig resource (and Service) can be placed in a namespace with a metadata namespace designation in your yaml.

```yaml
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
```

Answer (score 2):

**So far you cannot do it from the YAML file.**

There is a open feature request at the moment that I advise you to subscribe and to follow:

- https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-gce/issues/28

They were already discussing regarding this change in 2016: [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/32273).

> "Specific use case: GCE backends are provisioned with a default timeout of 30 seconds, which is not sufficient for some long requests. I'd like to be able to control the timeout per-backend."

**However** I would suggest you to check this part of the Google Cloud Documentation talking specifically regarding [configurable response timeou](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/#timeouts_and_retries)t.

**UPDATE**
Check the issue because they are making progresses

> I see there was a v1.0.0 release 18 days ago. Was this the completion of the major refactoring you talked about @nicksardo ?
>   Is it possible yet to configure how long a connection can be idle before the LB closes it?
>   **UPDATE**
>   The issue mentioned above is now closed and documentation for setting the timeout (and other backend service settings) is available here:
>   https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service